# Setting dimensions of 3D space in OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl, 3d, glut

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <freeglut.h>
#include <FreeImage.h>

void display(void) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    GLint viewport[4];
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
    double aspect = (double)viewport[2] / (double)viewport[3];
    gluPerspective(60, aspect, 1, 100);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0,0,-35);
    static float angle = 0;
    angle += 4.0f;
    //magenta middle cube
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(angle, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5);
    glColor3ub(224,8,133);
    glutSolidCube(5);
    glPopMatrix();
    //yellow right cube
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(10, 5, 0);
    glRotatef(angle, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1);
    glColor3ub(250, 224, 20);
    glutSolidCube(5);
    glPopMatrix();
    //cyan left cube
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-10, -5, 0);
    glRotatef(angle, 0.3, 0.2, 0.6);
    glColor3ub(0, 162, 211);
    glutSolidCube(5);
    glPopMatrix();
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void repeat(int val) {
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(10, repeat, 0);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
    glutCreateWindow("SIMPLE DISPLAY");
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-500,500,-500,500,-500,500);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutTimerFunc(0, repeat, 0);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

I have code that draws three cubes in 3-space and rotates them. I noticed the working area is very small despite using `glOrtho(-500,500,-500,500,-500,500)`. Translating the cubes in three directions makes it seems like the working area is only 50x50x50 (not sure on the z-dimensions, as it'll go 50 back before it disappears but can't confirm distance in front). Translating a cube 25 to the left or right makes it go out of the window bounds.

I thought `glOrtho()` set the working area size, in this case 1000x1000x1000?

Comment: You should definitely add ALL the relevant code to the question itself. Otherwise this question and answers do not make sense when the pastebin code is deleted.

Comment: I thought the code was perhaps too long to put in the Q itself, but no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding the `glOrtho` call at the begin of the display function by the `gluPerspective` call. You can only have one projection applied, either perspective or orthographic.

`glOrtho` does not define the size of the screen but a orthographic projection matrix (which can somehow be seen as the size of the working area as long as the camera is not moved).